# Show the Person type Object on JList (with JScrollPane) with fireIntervalAdded() method

Tags: java, swing, java-8

ScreenShot of the Program
[image: A]

I'm working on a program that reads `Name,Height,Weight,Size (String,int,int,String)` and creates a Person type object. 
The input (not on a console ofcourse) should look like:

```
Mary (h=170, w=56, size=S)
John (h=160, w=76, size XL)
```

on JList w/ JScrollPane just after I click *Add*

I created a jButton:

```
JButton addPerson = new JButton("Add");
```

And then i added the new ActionListener

```
addPerson.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == addPerson) {
                    int Height = sliderHeight.getValue();
                    int Weight = sliderWeight.getValue();
                    String name = nameField.getText();
                    String size = (String) sizes.getSelectedItem();

                    if (name.length() > 0) {
                        model.addPerson(Height, Weight, name, size);

//The `model` here is an Object of ListData class.
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Enter the name.");
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

This is how my AbstarctModel class looks like:

```
private class ListData extends AbstractListModel<Person> {

        ArrayList<Person> lista = new ArrayList<Person>();

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return lista.size();
        }

        public void addPerson(int Height, int Weight, String name, String size) {

            lista.add(new Person(Height, Weight, name, size));
            fireIntervalAdded(this, 0, lista.size());
//I think the problem is somewhere here.
            System.out.println("Person added.");

            System.out.println("List size: " + getSize());

            for (Person p : lista) {
                System.out.println(p);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Person getElementAt(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
```

This works fine, the Person Object is created and added to the ArrayList.

**BUT**
It does not show up on the `JList` (just above the `JSliders`)

So, summing it up,
Person type Object is created, added to `ArrayList` BUT is now showing up on the `JList` after I use `fireIntervalAdded()` method.

Comment: Why do you report an interval of `[0, lista.size()]` when you only have added *one* element? Besides that, does your model have any significant advantage over `DefaultListModel<Person>`? Note further that you now can use lambda expressions to implement an `ActionLister` and you don’t need a `e.getSource() == addPerson` test when the only event source you ever added the listener to, is `addPerson`.

Comment: Oh, and it would be very strange if a `Person` showed up in the UI as long as `getElementAt` returns `null`.

Comment: Oh maan, that is why this method exists! Thank you. One more thing, could You please show me how to change my implementation to that with lambda? I've never used it before but I know I should.
Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your `ListData` implementation. First of all, your `getElementAt` returns `null` rather than a list element, so obviously, no list element can show up in the UI. Second, the intervals reported by an event should only reflect the affected elements, i.e. the added elements, not the entire data range.

A fixed version would look like

```
private static class ListData extends AbstractListModel<Person> {
    private final ArrayList<Person> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Person getElementAt(int index) {
        return lista.get(index);
    }

    public void addPerson(int height, int weight, String name, String size) {
        int index = lista.size();
        lista.add(index, new Person(height, weight, name, size));
        fireIntervalAdded(this, index, index);
    }
}
```

Note that unlike the Collection API (and most other APIs), Swing uses an *inclusive* end index, so we have to specify [`index, index`] here. When adding multiple elements at the end, we have to specify [`index, lista.size()-1`], whereas other APIs would expect just `lista.size()` as exclusive end index.

Note further, that the functionality of this model class overlaps with `DefaultListModel<Person>` which might be easier to use.

And you can use lambda expressions to implement `ActionListener`s:

```
JButton addPerson = new JButton("Add");
addPerson.addActionListener(event -> {
    int height = sliderHeight.getValue();
    int weight = sliderWeight.getValue();
    String name = nameField.getText();
    String size = (String) sizes.getSelectedItem();

    if (!name.isEmpty()) {
        model.addPerson(height, weight, name, size);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Enter the name.");
    }
});
```

The `e.getSource() == addPerson` test was unnecessary, as `addPerson` is the only one possible event source here.